# using purrr to catch errors with mapply

Tags: r, purrr, mapply

I am getting to grips with the package `purrr` and how it can be used to catch problems with code. I don't seem to understand the output when it is used with `mapply`. Below I have outlined a working example, is this the correct way to implement the code?

```
x.good <- c(2, 2, 3, 3)
x.bad <- c(2, 2, "A", 3)
y <- c(2, 2, 3, 3)
mapply(sum, x.good, y) # works just fine
mapply(sum, x.bad, y)  # understandably makes R unhappy

# Define a new function
library(purrr)
safe_sum <- safely(sum, otherwise=NA_real_)

# apply it
res <- mapply(safe_sum, x.bad, y)

res
       2      2      A      3     
result NA     NA     NA     NA    
error  List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
```

In the tutorials the `map` function is also used, is this required here as well?

### Update

running `map2` seems to only return errors?

```
map2(x.bad, y, safe_sum)
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
[1] NA

[[1]]$error
<simpleError in sum(..., na.rm = na.rm): invalid 'type' (character) of     argument>


[[2]]
[[2]]$result
[1] NA

[[2]]$error
<simpleError in sum(..., na.rm = na.rm): invalid 'type' (character) of argument>


[[3]]
[[3]]$result
[1] NA

[[3]]$error
<simpleError in sum(..., na.rm = na.rm): invalid 'type' (character) of argument>


[[4]]
[[4]]$result
[1] NA

[[4]]$error
<simpleError in sum(..., na.rm = na.rm): invalid 'type' (character) of argument>
```

Comment: `map`, `map2`, and `pmap` are similar to `lapply`, `mapply` with two arguments, and `mapply` with an arbitrary number of arguments. For example: `map2(x.bad, y, safe_sum)`.

Comment: The `mapply` have `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`.  you can change it to `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` or use `Map`

Comment: It's probably a good idea to stay within the `purrr` universe rather than mixing it with base R `apply`.  Anyway, output is what I'd expect: results are always NA and an informative message is stored in `error`, plus it is simplified to a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your x.bad is a character vector. That is the problem in this example. If you change x.bad into a list as in the safely examples it will work, because only "A" will be defined as character, the rest will be numeric.

```
x.bad <- list(2, 2, "A", 3)
y <- c(2, 2, 3, 3)

library(purrr)

safe_sum <- safely(sum, otherwise=NA_real_)
map2(x.bad, y, safe_sum)
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
[1] 4

[[1]]$error
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]]$result
[1] 4

[[2]]$error
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]]$result
[1] NA

[[3]]$error
<simpleError in sum(..., na.rm = na.rm): invalid 'type' (character) of argument>


[[4]]
[[4]]$result
[1] 6

[[4]]$error
NULL
```

Today a blog appeared that goes into a bit more detail with examples. You can find it [here](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/about-risks-and-side-effects-consult-your-purrr-macist/).